# Average position and click through rate (CTR) improved after Christmas

Tags: seo, google-search-console, ctr

I'm newbie with SEO and I have observed that around Christmas, my CTR% and average position for my website decreased considerably.

Before Christmas, at the beginning of December, I updated my sitemap.xml

After New Year, I updated my sitemap.xml again.  The updated sitemap was read by Google on the 4th of January. After New Year, I observed that the CTR% and average position have improved considerably.

How is that possible?

Comment: Whatever happened, you sitemap had nothing to do with it.  Sitemaps have very little to do with SEO.  Google uses them to discover new URLs and to resolve duplicate content.   They have little to do with which pages or indexed or how your site is ranked.  See [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox).

Comment: The sitemap has no influence with the SEO. Ok, but ... Do you know how it's possible that my average position and click through rate was worst in Christmas than now?

Comment: @JoséCarlos on holidays, and specially on Christmas all metrics are a deal worse than at usual days.

Comment: What is your site subject matter? Users interests/search patterns will change over the Christmas/holiday period as people's priorities generally take a different focus... maybe your content is not what users are searching for at that time?

Comment: @MrWhite The site is a shoe shoe shop. At least, in Spain usually to buy shoes for Christmas. So, I understand that in Christmas the traffic was higher than now, but the reality is that the traffic is higher now than in Christmas.